# How to refresh amp-date-display?

Tags: amp-html

I've made a little clock for my website with [amp-date-display](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-date-display/?format=websites). The code below is OK. But, is there a way to refresh the code automatically every second so as to get a dynamic clock?

```
<amp-date-display datetime="now" display-in="utc" offset-seconds="3600" locale="fr" layout="flex-item">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{hourTwoDigit}}:{{minuteTwoDigit}}:{{secondTwoDigit}}
    </template>
</amp-date-display>
```